# const is the ailment that is killing my C++ programs. What happened this time?

Tags: c++

I have a class that is like

```
class HtmlRover
{
public:
    HtmlRover(const std::string::const_iterator &, const std::string::const_iterator &);
    ~HtmlRover();
    // ...
private:
    /...
    std::string::const_iterator _curIter;
    const std::string::const_iterator _offend;
    /...
};
```

and my compiler is complaining about my instantiation of `_offend` in the implementation of the constructor:

```
HtmlRover::HtmlRover(const std::string::const_iterator & it1, const std::string::const_iterator & it2)
{
    _curIter = it1;
    _offend = it2; 
}
```

It says

```
No vaiable overload "="
```

Now I understand this probably has something to do with a `const` variable being set to a reference of a variable, but then again the reference is also `const`, so what's the problem? I know that `const` variables cannot exist without being initialized, but that also should not be a problem since `_offend` is getting initialized right when an `HtmlRover` object is initialized.

Comment: Instead of trying to fix the syntax issue, i'd first ask yourself why a Rover object would ever need to cache an iterator. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell

Comment: `+1` for the question title, `-1` for the question based in misconception and bad coding style (not using initializer lists).

Comment: Use initialization list, as it is now `_offend` is using the assignment operator which is obviously a no go since it's const.

Comment: @rubenvb: I know the old title had a nice alliteration, but it's hardly PC. But I don't want an edit war with you so if you feel strongly about the original form, change it back.

Comment: PC? It's an expression in the English language. It saved me from downvoting the question..

Comment: @rubenvb Honest question: Why the `-1` for the question based on what sounds like programmer inexperience? If we downvote and reject questions with inexperienced code, then we've kind of defeated part of the purpose of SO.

Comment: @ajp5243 It is important for a beginner to at least grasp the important constructs of a language, in this case the inability to assign to a `const` object (which is quite apparent here, unlike e.g. in a `const` member function where the `this` pointer makes everything muddy in error messages) and the constructor's initiliazer list. Every piece of decent tutorial mentions that `const` members (and reference members) are exactly what the initializer list is required for. That and the existence of an exact duplicate. But hey, as everything I put on this site, it's just my opinion `;-)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As `_offend` is `const` you need to use a *base member initialiser* to set its value:

```
HtmlRover::HtmlRover(const std::string::const_iterator & it1, const std::string::const_iterator & it2) :
   _offend(it2)
{
    _curIter = it1;     
}
```

It would be a good idea to treat `_curIter` similarly although the language will not insist on that.

Answer (score 6):

You have to initialize const members in an initializer list:

```
HtmlRover::HtmlRover(const std::string::const_iterator & it1, 
                     const std::string::const_iterator & it2)
: _curIter(it1) // can be here
, _offend(it2) // must be here
{
}
```

Comment: @Bathsheba is correct too but I prefer this answer since it is always better to use an initializer list when possible, even for other members than references.

Comment: Yes this answer has more concision than mine, have an upvote!